# startall.sh command does not start NameNode in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

sh starts all the service like JPS , SecondaryNameNode , TaskTracker & JobTracker except the NameNode .

The only way i can start a NameNode is manually .

Also i am unable to access hnname:50070/ even when the NameNode is started .

I am a complete newbie to this please help .

Comment: can you look into the namenode logs located in the logs folder.It will tell you the error happened while startup

Comment: doublecheck if u have format the namenode or not

Answer (score 1):

Format the namenode before that remove your temp folder(contains datanode and namenode)

```
hadoop namenode -format
```

Comment: Can you tell what are the side effects of formatting namenode?

Comment: If namenode is formated then the data in the hadoop file system(hdfs) will be Removed. Because namenode contains the metadata about the data in datanode.